# Compiling C++ source for maximum portability

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, mingw, gnu, portability

I created a standalone executable using C++ and I want it to be usable by the largest number of people possible. In terms of compiler options what can I do to ensure this? I'm using MinGW with the linker option `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`. My probable users will be using Windows 7.

EDIT: I already made my source code as portable as I can. [This webpage](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/C++_Compiler) mentions the argument ANSI (-A) "for maximum portability". What affect does making it ANSI compatible have?

Comment: "Portability" means a lot more than just Windows (Seven or otherwise). Think Windows, Linux, Mac, x86, x86_64, ARM, ... and that's just the beginning of it! Compiler options are very little compared to the code you write.

Answer (score -1):

With g++ you can use a lot of warning flags. -Wall will already help, but there are many others such as those:

-Werror -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu++0x -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wdisabled-optimization -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-include-dirs -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wstrict-overflow=1 -Wundef -Wno-unused -Wunused-variable -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-parentheses -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wwrite-strings -Wswitch -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wnoexcept -Wold-style-cast -Wformat=2

It won't make your code compatible with all C++ compilers, however, it will help in reducing the work necessary once you try another compiler.

To see all those warning flags, check the man page or info page of g++.

Comment: -1 The question isn't about portability of source code to different compilers but about portability of the generated binary to different computers. Also, quite a few of those flags feel off (redundant, arguably harmful, contradictory) though I lack space and expertise to list specific complains.